# Common denominator cases tumah

Tags: commentaries, tamei-tahor-ritual-purity

Looking for a common denominator for all mentioned cases of tumah, trying to find something that would bind them together, I found that a thematic denominator is death (or loss of life, diminution of life actual or potential, they sensitize us to life, death, or maybe better mortality/physicality), and in order to remove the state of tumah water seems to be the key.

Are there more common denominators between all of these cases? And if we consider the state of taharah to be its opposite then what is the common denominator between the cases we consider something or someone to be in a state of taharah? And why does water helps to transform tumah in a non-tumah state if it’s not considered to be something physical?

Comment: Tumas keri is generated even when emitted during intercourse which is the opposite of death—it is the production of life. Ditto for tumas yoledes.

Answer (score 1):

The Kuzari says your answer, 2(60) - well done!
But see also my answer on [What do the terms tahor, tamey, taharah and tumah add to the description that one isn’t allowed to enter the tempel under certain circumstances](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/questions/113792/what-do-the-terms-tahor-tamey-taharah-and-tumah-add-to-the-description-that-on/113796#113796) Short form: 'Tumah ("blocked") *by definition* means inability to become kadosh, holy... whenever you call something tamei, you need to be ready to describe which kedushah it blocks.'

Comment: Could you provide some examples? What do I have to think about when we’re talking about food and giving birth, for example, what kind of kedushah do they block? I can imagine they somehow do, but it would make things more clear if you would provide a couple of examples.

Comment: See the post over there, lots of examples. It also has a link to my book, which has even more examples. Unless you insist, I'd rather not try to post them twice.